# CalDav server for custom Calendar

Tags: php, calendar, caldav

I'm trying to look in to a CalDav implementation in my own custom calendar.
At the moment I have a jquery/bootstrap calendar functioning with a MySQL database, what I'd like to do now is have that database sync with my phone using CalDav. Does anyone know what I might need to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather broad question but a good starting point is http://calconnect.org/caldav/ . The implementation section especially has a pretty decent list of libraries and open source projects.

Comment: That's a nice list of caldav servers, I'll take a look through them.